# Major boot problems

Tags: windows-10, boot

I've got major boot issues with my new Alienware :( pls help

I got it in recently, and used Macrium Reflect to make an image of my previous Windows installation to put on the computer. Before doing this, I also made a backup of what was on the Alienware.

It seemed to work mostly fine, but I figured after a bit that I'd rather do a clean install after all. I tried to restore the backup of the Alienware OEM install to the drive, but after re-imaging it to the drive, Windows wouldn't load. It would crash at boot no matter what I did or what startup repair options I would try.

I then used the command line and wiped all data from the SSD and HDD and made a Dell OS Recovery USB stick to install Windows - it would get up to the Dell SupportOS recovery loading screen and then freeze every time.

With that not working, I made a Windows Media Creation USB stick, although I know that gives you a base Windows install with no Alienware-specific drivers or settings, and that installs the first bit okay before rebooting and freezing at "Getting Devices Ready", crashing with a "clock_watchdog_timeout" blue screen. It does this every time.

It seems like there's literally nothing I can do here. Any ideas? :(

Comment: I hate to say it, but you'll probably have to contact support. hopefully they can help you get their recovery stuff working, or get you through installing via your WMC usb. I've had cases where they directed me to non-public bios'es for specific cases like replacing the ram. best of luck

Comment: My addendum to this is that restoring the Macrium Reflect image from my previous Windows installation once more still hangs at the spinning dots, but it BOOTS SUCCESSFULLY if I boot into Safe Mode - that works! Could this help me identify where the problem lies?

Comment: Run the hardware tests. from the bios